# Firewall not working in wcf services.

Tags: c#, wcf, port, firewall, wsdualhttpbinding

I am using WCF `WSDualHttpBinding` Service.
Service is hosted on server

`http://...:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/`

It works properly when firewall is closed on client and server.

I added port 8731 to allow-rule, but still does not work.
Which port should I open to enable communication to service and callback to client?

Comment: did you specify inbound on server ?

Comment: What port does the client use? Can you telnet the client from the server and vice versa?

Comment: How are you hosting the Service (in Cassini? WebDev Server? or self hosted?)...Allow 8731 on the Server as you have done, but you also need to open the port for callback on the client. Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://mleder.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/wcf-callback-port-for-wsdualhttpbinding.html - you need to open that port on the client.

Comment: @FelicePollano on server firewall is temporarily disable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments I finally found solution.

Lack of field `clientBaseAddress="http://ip:port"` in binding configuration. There I can define port, and add to firewall rule